# How to protect a specific url through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, passwords, .htpasswd

I want to add a login restriction on certain page like.

```
www.example.com/testing
```

whenever someone hit this url it should ask password, otherwise whole website should work password free.

**Htaccess Code:**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/testing-softwares SECURED

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nrl_shareware/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc_shareware/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Htpasswd Code:**

```
test:$apr1$O9AK9s5s$H0IuOqkTnB0yJ5k35kX2a1
```

---

**Updated Code**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/testing-softwares SECURED

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "D:/DONT DELETE 80-261209/ABCProjects/xampp/htdocs/abc_shareware/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc_shareware/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc_shareware/index.php [L]
</IfModule>




# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it this way with `mod_setenvif`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/testing SECURED

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

Comment: not working ..even the `testing` page is opening without any password protection. No prompt appearing. Have a look at my htaccess code

Comment: what should be /path/to/your/.htpasswd htapsswd is located in root

Comment: server error is appearing now when i changed the path while echoing `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];`

Comment: `AuthUserFile takes one argument, text file containing user IDs and passwords` This error is appearing in error logs

Comment: is this wrong? `AuthUserFile D:/DONT DELETE 80-261209/ABCProjects/xampp/htdocs/abc_shareware/.htpasswd`

Comment: means path in double qoutes ?

Comment: Not working No errors. Please have a look at my question under `Updated Code`. I have pasted the htaccess code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115276/discussion-between-moeed-farooqui-and-anubhava).